# Connect to SSAS OLAP Cube Using Python

Tags: python, ssas, olap, xmla

Looking for resources to learn how to connect and fetch data from SSAS OLAP Cube.

Found I can do it with XMLA lib, but found no resources to explore and learn.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use python to connect SSAS cube, you could refer to [SSAS via Python](http://blog.soft-prestidigitation.com/ssas-via-python.html)  and [olap.xmla](https://github.com/may-day/olap)  for more details.

Zoe